# Why doesn't next-sitemap work properly with next-auth?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, sitemap, next-auth

repo: https://github.com/Skolaczk/next-starter

After adding next-auth to my app next-sitemap doesn't generate sitemap properly. The result of building the app before and adding next-auth to the photos. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

I tried adding this line to sitemap.config.js:

```
exclude: ['/api/auth/*']
```

, but it didn't help.

Sitemap before adding next-auth:

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<sitemap>
<loc>http://localhost:3000/sitemap-0.xml</loc>
</sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

Sitemap after adding next-auth:

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"> </sitemapindex>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GA2t.png)

I expect the problem to be solved